# TeXlipse and BibTeX8 builder

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, texlipse

I am using TeXlispe and BibLaTeX and want to use BibTeX8, because it solves some sorting issues bibtex.exe can't handle.

How can I add programs to the Builder Settings?

Comment: why are you using bibtex with biblatex? The default biber has far more extensive sorting possibilities than bibtex or bibtex8?

Comment: http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/manual/config.html has some details. Maybe that helps.

Comment: @moewe, no it doesn't say anything about how to add builder settings. :(

Comment: @David Carlisle: Let me reformulate the question more generally: How can one add arbitrary programs to the build tools?

Comment: That is an eclipse question more than a tex one so you may get better help in a different place but hopefully an eclipse user will see and be able to answer.